# Java: Breaking Loop

Tags: java, loops, break

What is the best way to implement the following pseudo-code in java?

```
method_one():
    while(condition_one):
        EXECUTE method_two();     // (A)

method_two():
    while(condition_two):
        EXECUTE method_three();   // (B)

method_three():
     if (condition_three):
        GOTO EXECUTE method_two();
     else:
        //do some stuff
```

Edit: Thanks for prompt replies, everybody. Helped a lot. Figured it out now.

Comment: Do you literally want these to be three separate methods?

Comment: Will `condition_one` be true when `condition_three` is true in `method_three`?  If so, you can just call `method_one` instead of a `goto`.  I believe Java doesn't have tail call elimination, so you can't do that too often.  Do you need three separate methods for the loops?  It might be easier to write a single state machine in a single method that does the same logic.

Comment: okay, clarification time: method one and two do nothing but call the next one down the list, correct? Method 3 is the only one that does something interesting?

Comment: Your psuedo code is a fine example of "infinite recursion"  If condition_three is true the loop never exits.

Comment: What is the difference between `GOTO EXECUTE method_two();` and `EXECUTE method_two()` ?

Comment: @Chip I think the difference he's trying to make here is that `EXECUTE method_two()` actually performs the call - that is, it makes a context switch by pushing onto the stack, whereas `GOTO EXECUTE method_two()` resumes the previous execution - that is, it's a return (pops the context off the stack).

Comment: Are methods one and two doing anything else besides waiting to run another method? Are they doing anything substantial?

Comment: I added two marks (A and B). When you say `GOTO EXECUTE method_two()`, to which mark do you want to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need separate methods, this should be equivalent:

```
boolean exit_from_three = false;
while (condition_one || exit_from_three) {
    exit_from_three = false;
    while (condition_two) {
        if (condition_three) {exit_from_three = true; break;}
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, the reason I did this way is to make it "look" simpler.

Comment: @blackened: I just fixed it (made it more complicated) to handle the case in which `condition_three` is true but `condition_one` isn't; your code does not exit the `method_one` loop in that case, so I edited mine to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could do something like:

```
public void method_one() {
 while (condition_one) {
    method_two();
  }
}

public void method_two() {
  while (condition_two) {
    method_three();
  }
}

public void method_three() {
  if (condition_three) {
    return;
  } else {
    // do something magical
  }
}
```

Comment: Should the `if` in `method_two` be `while`?

Comment: How do you break out of that loop if `condition_three` is true?  Note that the `goto` goes to the body of the loop in `method_one`.

Comment: Well, I guess I was assuming that there was some form of other checking going on here - so condition_two and condition_one aren't dependent on what happens in method_three. I mean, it could be updated by a separate thread or something. Or, it could just be a set of static variables that are set in the else clause of method_three. It could be dependent, or perhaps not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've read the pseudo-code right, it's a pretty simple case of calling methods.  The only catch is that whatever represents conditions one, two, and three have to be updated somewhere or this will be an infinite loop at method_two (or method_one).

```
public class LoopingClass {

    private void method_one() {
        while(/* condition_one, where condition_one results in a boolean value */) {
            method_two();
        }
    }

    private void method_two() {
        while(/* condition_two, where condition_two results in a boolean value */) {
            method_three();
        }
    }

    private void method_three() {
        if(/* condition_three - where condition_three results in a boolean value */) {
            return;
        } else {
            // other stuff here
        }
    }
}
```